# NextJS with App Router: What is the correct way to return a 403/500 error

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-500

Best I can find on the docs say to use this: `return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' }, { status: 500 })`. However, in use, this just returns the string `"{"error":"Internal Server Error"}"` and doesn't trigger any default error pages. Using the pages router, default error pages are provided, so I'm assuming this is also the case using the App Router. Is there any better way to deal with these common error codes without writing a whole custom error page?

The same thing happens with `{ status: 403}` and `{ status: 404 }`.